# Фильтр по столбцу в C#

Tags: c#, access, datagrid

Передо мной встала такая проблема:

Нужно выполнить фильтр по столбцам 
[image: мы выбираем из combobox столбец в textbox пишем данные которые нам нужны]

Проблема состоит в том что при выборе столбца "Тематика_Газеты" или "Цвет_Печать" выдает ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]Знаю что like использовать нельзя, подскажите как реализовать по другому?

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (textBox2.Text != "")
     {
         название_газетыBindingSource.Filter = comboBox1.Text + " Like'*" + textBox2.Text + "*'";
         название_газетыBindingSource.Filter = comboBox1.Text + '=' + textBox2.Text;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, поля `Тематика_Газеты` и `Цвет_Печать` у вас целочисленные - в них содержатся идентификаторы (номера) соответствующих тематик и цветов.

Попробуйте:

1. Доставать из комбобоксов не текст, а соответствующий идентификатор тематики или цвета.
2. Заменить фильтр `like` на `=` с подставновкой выбранного идентификатора.

Comment: смысл мне понятен,но не совсем понятна технология выполнения,ведь в combobox я сам выписывал название столбцов.

Comment: Проблема не в названии столбцов. Проблема в том, что значение в столбце - это целое число - 1, 2, 3. А вы его фильтруете как строчку. Ваш код берет число 1 и пытается понять, соответствует ли оно фильтру `like '*Экономика*'`. И на этом падает.

Comment: т.е. мне надо еще делать проверку какой стобец?числовой или строковый.

Comment: Вам нужно делать провеку целочисленного столбца (как сейчас сделано) но с целочисленным значением (а сейчас вы его со строчкой стравниваете).

Comment: все же я не могу понять как вытащить индетификатор и с помощью него искать запись.